# Write a Morse Calculator

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, morse

Write a program or function that takes a mathematical expression in Morse code as input, and returns the solution in Morse code.

Valid operations are plus: `+` and minus: `_` (underscore). You can assume you will only receive non-negative integer input, and that the result will be non-negative.

The expression will contain at least two terms, and maximum ten terms. There won't be two adjacent operators i.e. `.----+_-....`, and there won't be parentheses.

Digits are seperated by single spaces. You can choose to have the operators separated from the numbers by a single space on each side (see examples).

The Morse equivalent for the digits 0-9 are:

```
0  -----
1  .----
2  ..---
3  ...--
4  ....-
5  .....
6  -....
7  --...
8  ---..
9  ----.
```

**Examples:**

```
Input
Output


.----+.----  (1+1=2) Optional input: .---- + .----
..---

-...._...--  (6-3=3) Optional input: -.... _ ...--
...--

..---_...--+..--- (2-3+2=1)
1

..---+...--_....-+---.._.....  (2+3-4+8-5=4)
....-

.---- ..---_-....+...-- ...--  (12-6+33=39)
...-- ----.

----. -----+----.+..--- ----._..... .....+---..+-...._.----+----.+----._..--- -----  (90+9+29-55+8+6-1+9+9-20=84)
---.. ....-
```

Standard rules regarding I/O formats etc. apply. A few trailing spaces, and a single newline are accepted. You can't split the number over several lines. You can't use `eval` or equivalent.

This is code golf, so the shortest code in bytes win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pyth, <s>69</s> 63 bytes

```
J_.:s*R5"-.-"5jdm@Jsd`s*MC,mssdc`MKmxJdcz)"-1"+1mtyq\+@cz)dx_1K
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J_.%3As%2aR5%22-.-%225jdm%40Jsd%60s%2aMC%2Cmssdc%60MKmxJdcz%29%22-1%22%2B1mtyq%5C%2B%40cz%29dx_1K&input=.----+..---+_+-....+%2B+...--+...--&test_suite_input=.----+%2B+.----%0A-....+_+...--%0A..---+%2B+...--+_+....-+%2B+---..+_+.....%0A.----+..---+_+-....+%2B+...--+...--%0A----.+-----+%2B+----.+%2B+..---+----.+_+.....+.....+%2B+---..+%2B+-....+_+.----+%2B+----.+%2B+----.+_+..---+-----&debug=0)

[Or use a test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J_.%3As%2aR5%22-.-%225jdm%40Jsd%60s%2aMC%2Cmssdc%60MKmxJdcz%29%22-1%22%2B1mtyq%5C%2B%40cz%29dx_1K&input=.----+..---+_+-....+%2B+...--+...--&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=.----+%2B+.----%0A-....+_+...--%0A..---+%2B+...--+_+....-+%2B+---..+_+.....%0A.----+..---+_+-....+%2B+...--+...--%0A----.+-----+%2B+----.+%2B+..---+----.+_+.....+.....+%2B+---..+%2B+-....+_+.----+%2B+----.+%2B+----.+_+..---+-----&debug=0)

Explanation

```
J_.:s*R5"-.-"5                                                  - Construct the morse sequence 0-10
              jd                                                - Prettify output (join by spaces)
                m@Jsd                                           - Get the morse for each character in output
                     `s                                         - Convert to a string
                         C,mssdc`MKmxJdcz)"-1"                  - Get the numbers
                       *M                                       - Multiply the numbers by the operators
                                              +1mtyq\+@cz)dx_1K - Turn `+` and `_` to +-1
```

Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Jakube!

Comment: `J_.:s*R5"-.-"5` for constructing the numbers. Probably even shorten when using packed strings.

Answer (score 5):

## Retina, 132 bytes

A messy, first pass solution.

```
(-)+\.+
5$*.$#1$*.
(-|(\.))+ ?
$#2
\d+
$*
+`(1(_)1|(_1+)|_|\+)(.*)
$2$4$3
1+
$.0
\d
$*x5$*- 
(x)+x{5}-*
$#1$*-xxxx
(\S{5})\S*
$1
x
.
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=KC0pK1wuKwo1JCouJCMxJCouCigtfChcLikpKyA_CiQjMgpcZCsKJCoKK2AoMShfKTF8KF8xKyl8X3xcKykoLiopCiQyJDQkMwoxKwokLjAKXGQKJCp4NSQqLSAKKHgpK3h7NX0tKgokIzEkKi14eHh4CihcU3s1fSlcUyoKJDEKeAou&input=Li0tLS0rLi0tLS0KLi4tLS0KCi0uLi4uXy4uLi0tCi4uLi0tCgouLi0tLSsuLi4tLV8uLi4uLSstLS0uLl8uLi4uLgouLi4uLQoKLi0tLS0gLi4tLS1fLS4uLi4rLi4uLS0gLi4uLS0KLi4uLS0gLS0tLS4KCi0tLS0uIC0tLS0tKy0tLS0uKy4uLS0tIC0tLS0uXy4uLi4uIC4uLi4uKy0tLS4uKy0uLi4uXy4tLS0tKy0tLS0uKy0tLS0uXy4uLS0tIC0tLS0tCi0tLS4uIC4uLi4t)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>75</s> <s>71</s> <s>69</s> 68 bytes

```
5:t!<t~v45+cXIO1Oj6ZC"@2#0)Iw!Xmfqb+wXK32=?10*}*+K?K9\6-O}V47-Y)Z{Zc
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=NTp0ITx0fnY0NStjWElPMU9qNlpDIkAyIzApSXchWG1mcWIrd1hLMzI9PzEwKn0qK0s_SzlcNi1PfVY0Ny1ZKVp7WmM&input=LS0tLS4gLS0tLS0rLS0tLS4rLi4tLS0gLS0tLS5fLi4uLi4gLi4uLi4rLS0tLi4rLS4uLi5fLi0tLS0rLS0tLS4rLS0tLS5fLi4tLS0gLS0tLS0)

#### General explanation

I use code format in the following so that indentation expresses the nesting of operations.

```
The input is split into chunks of 6 characters. The last chunk will have
5 characters padded by a 0 char.
   A 0 is initially pushed. This will contain the accumulated global result.
      Each operand (sequence of digits) is processed as follows. A "sign digit",
      1 or -1, has been previously pushed according to whether the preceding
      operator was + or - (for the first operand 1 is used as sign digit).
      Then a 0 is pushed. This will contain the accumulated operand value.
         Each digit of the operand is transformed into the a number `0`...`9` and
         accumulated to the operand value, with successive multiplications by `10`.
      When a + or - is detected, the current operand is finished. So it is 
      multiplied by its sign digit, and added to the acumulated global result.
      A new sign digit is pushed (1 for +, -1 for -), and a new 0 is pushed
      as initial accumulated operand value for the next operand.
   When a 0 char is detected instead of + or -, this marks the end of the input.
   The current global accumulated result is the definitive value. This is
   tranformed into Morse digits and displayed.
```

#### Detailed explanation

```
5:t!<         % first half of the 10x5 array of Morse digits, with 0 for - and 1 for .
t~v           % vertically concat second half, i.e. first half vertically flipped
45+cXI        % transform 0 1 to chars - . Copy this "digit table" to clipboard I
O             % push 0: initial value for accumulated global result
1             % push 1: sign digit for first operand
O             % push 0: initial value of operand
j             % input string
6ZC           % arrange 6-length non-overlapping blocks as columns. Last is 0-padded
"             %   for each column
  @           %   push column
  2#0)        %   split into last element and vector or remaining elements
  I           %   push digit table
  w!          %   swap and transposed into a row
  Xmfq        %   index of that row in the digit table. Subtract 1: gives the digit
  b+          %   bubble up current operand value to top. Add to the new found digit
  wXK         %   swap last char of column (+,-,space,0) to top. Copy to clipboard K
  32=         %   is it space?
  ?           %   if so
    10*       %     multiply by 10. The operand will continue with next digit
  }           %   else: the operand is done
    *         %     multiply by sign digit
    +         %     add this operand with its sign to accumulated global result
    K         %     push last char of column again
    ?         %     if it's not 0
      K9\6-   %       push 1 if it's a +, -1 if it's a -: sign digit of next operand
      O       %       push 0 to initiallize accumulated operand value of next operand
    }         %     else: it's a 0: we're done computing the result
      V       %       convert result to string to get its digits
      47-Y)   %       index the rows of the digit table that was initially pushed
      Z{Zc    %       join rows by spaces
              %     end if, implicit
              %   end if, implicit
              % end for each, implicit
              % display, implicit
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (es6) 236 bytes

plenty of room for improvement

```js
q=>(q.replace(/[.-]{5}/g,q=>(a=q.split`.`.length)&&q[4]=='-'?a-1:11-a).replace(/ /g,'').split(/([_+])/).reduce((l,o)=>l+(+o?(n=='_'?-(+o):+o):(n=o)&&0),0,n='')+[]).split``.map(u=>(((a='.....')+'-----').slice(5-u)+a).substr(0,5)).join` `
```

---

broken up

```
q=>
 (
 //grab each set of 5 dits/dahs
 q.replace(/[.-]{5}/g,


  //count dits
  //if last digit is '-' return dits-1
  //else return 11-dits
  q=>(a=q.split`.`.length)&&q[4]=='-'?a-1:11-a)

   //remove spaces and split on operators + and _
   .replace(/ /g,'').split(/([_+])/)

    //reduce the array into one element
    //start with 0;
    //when we come across a number add it to the total
    //when we come across an operator change current op to it
    .reduce((l,o)=>l+(+o?(n=='_'?-(+o):+o):(n=o)&&0),0,n='')

  //cast to string
  +[])

 //turn to array
 .split``

  //turn each digit back to morse
  .map(u=>(".....-----".slice(5-u)+'.....').substr(0,5)).join` `
```

*usage*

```js
f=q=>(q.replace(/[.-]{5}/g,q=>(a=q.split`.`.length)&&q[4]=='-'?a-1:11-a).replace(/ /g,'').split(/([_+])/).reduce((l,o)=>l+(+o?(n=='_'?-(+o):+o):(n=o)&&0),0,n='')+[]).split``.map(u=>(((a='.....')+'-----').slice(5-u)+a).substr(0,5)).join` `

f("----. -----+----.+..--- ----._..... .....+---..+-...._.----+----.+----._..--- -----")
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Pure bash, <s>366</s> 317

```
a=----- p='v+=($a);a=${a/-/.}';q=${p/-?././-};. <(echo $p{,,,,} $q{,,,,});p(){
[ ${1:0:1} = . ]&&{ b=${1%%-*};o+=${#b};}||{ b=${1%%.*} o+=$[(5+${#b})%10];};}
s=${1//[-.]/};for i in ${1//[+_]/ };do p $i;t=${s:0:1};o+=${t// };s=${s:1};done
r=$[${o//_/-}];for ((i=0;i<${#r};i++));do w+=(${v[${r:i:1}]});done;echo ${w[@]}
```

Ok, I could save 10 bytes to reach **307** by written 1st line:

```
v=(----- .---- ..--- ...-- ....- ..... -.... --... ---.. ----.);p(){
```

instead of (but I like):

```
a=----- p='v+=($a);a=${a/-/.}';q=${p/-?././-};. <(echo $p{,,,,} $q{,,,,});p(){
```

Sample:

```
cat >/tmp/morseCalc.sh <<'eof'
#!/bin/bash
a=----- p='v+=($a);a=${a/-/.}';q=${p/-?././-};. <(echo $p{,,,,} $q{,,,,});p(){
[ ${1:0:1} = . ]&&{ b=${1%%-*};o+=${#b};}||{ b=${1%%.*} o+=$[(5+${#b})%10];};}
s=${1//[-.]/};for i in ${1//[+_]/ };do p $i;t=${s:0:1};o+=${t// };s=${s:1};done
r=$[${o//_/-}];for ((i=0;i<${#r};i++));do w+=(${v[${r:i:1}]});done;echo ${w[@]}
eof
chmod +x /tmp/morseCalc.sh

for test in 1+1 6-3 2-3+2 2+3-4+8-5 12-6+33 90+9+29-55+8+6-1+9+9-20 ;do
    string="$(sed 's/ \.\.\.-\.-$//;s/ \.-\.-\. /+/g;s/ -\.\.\.\.- /_/g' <(
        xargs < <(morse -s -- $test)))"
    out="$(/tmp/morseCalc.sh "$string")"
    res=$(morse -sd <<< "$out")
    echo "$test: $string = $out -> $res"
  done |
    fold -w 80 -s

1+1: .----+.---- = ..--- -> 2
6-3: -...._...-- = ...-- -> 3
2-3+2: ..---_...--+..--- = .---- -> 1
2+3-4+8-5: ..---+...--_....-+---.._..... = ....- -> 4
12-6+33: .---- ..---_-....+...-- ...-- = ...-- ----. -> 39
90+9+29-55+8+6-1+9+9-20: ----. -----+----.+..--- ----._..... 
.....+---..+-...._.----+----.+----._..--- ----- = ---.. ....- -> 84
```

or if `morse` converter is not installed:

```
for test in .----+.---- -...._...-- ..---_...--+..---  \
 ..---+...--_....-+---.._..... ".---- ..---_-....+...-- ...--" "----. -----+\
----.+..--- ----._..... .....+---..+-...._.----+----.+----._..--- -----" ;do
    echo $test $(
        bash <(sed '$s/;f/;echo "(${o\/\/_\/-}=$r)";f/' /tmp/morseCalc.sh
            ) "$test" )
  done |
    fold -w80 -s

.----+.---- (1+1=2) ..---
-...._...-- (6-3=3) ...--
..---_...--+..--- (2-3+2=1) .----
..---+...--_....-+---.._..... (2+3-4+8-5=4) ....-
.---- ..---_-....+...-- ...-- (12-6+33=39) ...-- ----.
----. -----+----.+..--- ----._..... .....+---..+-...._.----+----.+----._..--- 
----- (90+9+29-55+8+6-1+9+9-20=84) ---.. ....-
```